# java - how do I save and load a list with db4o

Tags: java, db4o

I don't want to save the full class so I save List with this code

```
connection.store(myObject.getList())
```

And How do I load my list?

(db.query(List) doesnt work)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend to store plain lists. The reason is that you cannot really query for a list with certain content. You only can get all lists back with (I didn't check if it works):

```
 // This returns all stored lists
 List<List> result = db.query(List.class);
```

So I recommend the create a object which holds your list and query for those objects. Then it also easy to distiguish between diffrent types of list: You can create different holder classes or itroduce meta information on the holder object.

Just another detail: db4o cannot index the content of a collection. That means queries which look if a collection contains certain members will be slow.